# Google Sheets getting Invalid error in drop down but item is on the list

Tags: validation, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I created a data validation cell to select different time slots. I am getting an error when choosing 6:00, 7:00, 8:00, 9:00 even tho all of them are in the  list. Error says: "Invalid: Input must be an item on the specified list"
Added the data validation like this: [image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

The file is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSBx87sWScwe2Vtp9FOcH3BupvPJ_jzISUeAk6gSBOM/edit#gid=612415402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to actually pick a choice on the dropdown OR your input is exactly the same with the choice.

By default, when you manually enter `6:00-9:00` it automatically adds `0` in the beginning as sheets has detected your input as time.

So you should update your data validation list to use `06:00-09:00` instead so it matches when sheets adjusts your input when they are manually entered.

Comment: Hi @Mel, if we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks. I didn't know.